# Worker Thread synchronisation in .NET

Tags: vb.net, thread-safety

I understand that ASP.NET has worker threads and IO threads.  You can also create your own threads using: System.Threading.Thread.

Please see the code below:

```
SyncLock myLogFile
    myLogFile.WriteLine("message");
End SyncLock
```

If you do not create any instances of System.Thread in an ASP.NET application, then is it necessary to synchronize access to the log file?  If there are multiple users concurrently accessing the web application then it could mean multiple worker threads are writing to the log file at the same time.

I have read questions like this: [Synchronization in multi threading in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3687776/synchronization-in-multi-threading-in-net), but I have not found an answer to my question.

I actually use Log4Net for logging in .NET application.  The purpose of this question is to satisfy curiosity.

Comment: your question isn't clear. Are you asking how log4Net is able to do logging in a multi-threaded .net application like asp.net?

Comment: @deostroll, I am asking if synchronization is ever needed in a single threaded ASP.NET application i.e. an application that does not explicitly create an threads (System.Threading.Thread)

Comment: No, of course not.  Log4Net already contains such a lock anyway.

Comment: @Hans Passant, the reason I referenced log4net in the question is to discourage answers like: "please use log4net for logging" (as I used logging in the example code).  I am specifically asking if synchronization is ever needed in a single threaded .NET application as .NET applications have multiple worker threads.

Comment: @w0051977 No, you never need synchronization in a single-threaded application. Why do you say 'single-threaded', though? Your question is about multi-threaded applications. Once you create a thread other than the main thread, you almost always need synchronization.

Comment: @xxbbcc, even with ASP.NET that allows multiple worker threads for concurrent access?

Comment: @xxbbcc, could you provide an example of where synchronization is needed in a single threaded ASP.NET app? That would answer my question.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a down-vote, whoever did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The need for synchronization depends on what you do. In a single-threaded application, you don't need to synchronize threads because there's only one so you won't encounter any threading issues - there are no shared resources that may be accessed by multiple threads.

In a multi-threaded application the need for synchronization depends on what resources you're trying to access. If you don't try to access any shared resources (that is, each thread only ever works with data local to the thread) there's nothing to synchronize so you don't need locking. This is a very rare scenario, though.

ASP.NET is heavily multi-threaded but most of the synchronization is done for you by IIS or the ASP.NET framework so you don't need to roll your own unless you try to share resources among your threads. Typically a request comes in, you get some data and produce a response - you don't need explicit synchronization because the `Application`, `Session`, etc. are already synchronized.

If you try to write to the same log file, however, from your request-handling threads, you need explicit synchronization - ASP.NET doesn't know about your file but having multiple threads trying to read/write the file without protection leads to problems. In this case you definitely need synchronization - unless someone is already doing it for you. If you use log4net - as Hans Passant commented - it already takes care of it, so you don't have to.

If you try to read/write an XML file, for example (not using any other wrapper library), you'd have to use `lock`-s or other synchronization primitives to protect the file - one thread may be writing it while several others may be trying to read it at the same time. To prevent the readers from getting garbage data (imagine that a write is interrupted by the CPU to switch to a different thread), you need to prevent the readers from reading until the write is complete.

Comment: Thanks, but asp.net has worker threads. If 86 users access the website concurrently then wouldn't 86 threads be created?

Comment: @w0051977 Yes, that'd be 86 worker threads created. Each and every request is handled on a separate thread. Depending on system resources the thread pool may not have enough threads - in that case fewer worker threads are used and the remaining requests go into the queue.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer suggests that the framework deals with this?

Comment: @w0051977 The framework deals with _certain parts_ of it. Internal ASP.NET objects are synchronized but if you try to share a resource of your own, _you must provide your own synchronization_.

Comment: @w0051977 log4net synchronizes file access internally so you don't have to. They did the work for you but in other situations you'd have to.

Comment: I am thinking of a different scenario to object sharing i.e. Context switching occuring in the middle of a function that could/should be synchronised.

Comment: @w0051977 I'm sorry, what do you mean? You're right, context switching interrupts a function but just because it does you don't necessarily need to synchronize that function. Even single-threaded applications are subject to context switches but they don't need to lock because they don't share data with others.